# Остановить анимацию и вызвать ее callback?

Tags: jquery, анимация, callback

Эксперты, необходимо остановить анимацию `jquery` и вызвать ***callback-функцию***, как остановить я знаю, `.stop(true, true)`, но как вызвать ***callback-функцию*** этой анимации - нет. Помогите.

Answer (score 1):

Объявляйте анонимную фунцкцию и передавайте ее в колбек. В чем проблема?

```
var animationCallback = function() {
    alert('Hello World');
}
jQuery("#selector").animate({left: "-=400"}, 1000, animationCallback);

.........

jQuery("#selector").stop(true, true);
animationCallback();
```

Либо, если у вас заверщающий колбек должен выполняться всегда, независимо от того завершилась анимация штатно или нет, то используйте опцию always:

```
$( "#selector" ).animate({left: "-=400"}, {
    duration: 1000,
    always: function() {
        alert('Hello World');
    }
});
```